# When anonfun$1 becomes anonfun$m1$1 (or vice versa) in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalac

Can anyone explain why Scala gives two different names in the following cases? Why couldn't Scala give the same names in each case?! Is there some kind of consistency I don't know yet? It must be related to eta-expansion, right?

```
object A {
  val ms: Seq[String => String] = Seq(m1)
  def m1(s: String) = s
}
A.ms.map(m => m.getClass.getSimpleName)
```

The above gives `List(anonfun$1)` - note the name of the element - `anonfun$1` while the following gives `anonfun$m1$1`. Why?

```
object A {
  val ms: Seq[String => String] = Seq(m1)
  def m1: String => String = s => s
}
A.ms.map(m => m.getClass.getSimpleName)
```

Could I also ask for a simpler case to demonstrate the difference (perhaps without using `Seq`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems compiler adds path into name when creates anonymous classes. Your example (pretty interesting in some other sense by the way) may be simplified down to:

```
def m1(s: String) = s
def m2: String => String = s => s
val ss: Seq[String => String] = Seq(m1, m2)
ss map (_.getClass.getSimpleName)
```

Which produces:

```
res28: Seq[String] = List(anonfun$1, anonfun$m2$1)
```

Without Seq:

```
(m1 _).getClass.getSimpleName
res34: String = anonfun$1

m2.getClass.getSimpleName
res35: String = anonfun$m2$1
```

Luckily `m1` in Seq is equivalent to `m1 _`, and `m2` is equivalent to method application.
What about names - compiler adds path to autogenerated classes, so, top-scope `m1` turns to `anonfun$1` (anonfun is default prefix for generated classes for functions), and because `m2` returns function from inside, that function gets one more element in path (name).

Interestingly, this weird thing:

```
def a() = {
  def b() = {
    def c() = {
      def d(): String => String = s => s
      d()
    }
    c()
  }
  b()
}
```

Has name:

```
a().getClass.getSimpleName
res30: String = anonfun$d$1$1
```

So, no trace of a, b, c! So, it's somewhat complicated, I tried but couldn't have found the exact choice and patterns of naming in compiler source, though reading was interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can observe symbol manipulation:

```
$ scala -Yshow-syms -uniqid -Dscala.repl.maxprintstring=8000
```

In the REPL, be forewarned, you'll see one ream of output for your wrapped code and then a second ream of output for the bit of code that prints your result.

```
scala> def m1: String => String = s => s

[[symbol layout at end of parser]]
* package scala#22 (final)

[[symbol layout at end of namer]]
* object $read#58183
* package $line6#58181 (final)
  package scala#22 (final)

[[symbol layout at end of packageobjects]]
  object $read#58183
  package $line6#58181 (final)
  package scala#22 (final)

[[symbol layout at end of typer]]
* class String#643 (final)
* constructor Object#3505
* object $read#58184
*     constructor $read#58188
*     object $iw#58190
*         constructor $iw#58192
*         object $iw#58193
*         object $iw#58194
*             constructor $iw#58196
*             method m1#58197
*                 value $anonfun#58199 (<synthetic>)
*                     value s#58200
```

...massive snip...

```
          object $iw#58194
              constructor $iw#58196
              method m1#58197
                  <$anon: Function1#2093> (final <synthetic>)
                      constructor $anonfun#58218


[[symbol layout at end of lambdalift]]
```

...snip...

```
          object $iw#58194
O             <$anon: Function1#2093> [Owner was method m1#58197, now object $iw#58194] (final <synthetic>)
                  constructor $anonfun$m1$1#58218
```

As the output says, the anonfun becomes a child of the enclosing class because it is implemented as a class; any captured variables are passed to its constructor.

A quick look at `LambdaLift.scala` shows that `newName` actually [special-cases anonymous functions that are owned by methods](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0-M7/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/LambdaLift.scala#L259), to have the name-mangling you've pointed out.

This is an easy way to avoid naming collisions such as:

```
scala> class Foo { def x = 1 to 10 map (2 * _) ; def y = 1 to 10 map (3 * _) filter (_ > 6) }
```

But since `newName` is getting a fresh name anyway, I would guess that retaining the method name is a debugging aid.

Is it a good debugging aid?

Multiple anonfuns in any method 'm' in a compilation unit will all be named `anonfun$m$1` and so on; there is no way to distinguish whether the `anonfun$m$3` belonged to `Foo.m` or `Bar.m`, except by inspecting those classes.

I would rely on the REPL to discover anonfuns for me, except currently it is no smarter than we are.